# Сортировка с условием

Tags: python, queryset, django

Как мне сделать такую штуку. Есть класс активности, есть класс занятия (урок). У каждой активности есть тип и дата. Количество типов конечно и мало. Мне надо отсортировать объекты типа занятие по дате активности определенного типа. Не могу понять как сделать. Можно ли замутить что-то подобное:

```
Leson.objects.filter(action__type="w").order_by(action__type="w", "-action__date").distinct()
```

Но естественно так работать не будет. А как написать так, чтоб работало?

**Обновление**: Идея в том, что сначала я фильтрую по типу активности, а затем хочу отсортировать по дате активности. Проблема в том, что надо отсортировать по активности определенного типа. К примеру, я отфильтровал объекты. У меня получилось следующее

Объект А имеет поля

```
активность { тип: "w", дата 11-01-01 }
активность { тип: "g", дата 11-04-07 }
активность { тип: "r", дата 11-03-06 }
....
```

Объект B имеет поля

```
активность { тип: "w", дата 11-10-01 }
активность { тип: "r", дата 11-03-03 }
....
```

То есть остались только те объекты, у которых есть активности типа "w". А вопрос в следующем, как теперь их отсортировать по дате активности типа "w"? Если просто написать `order_by("-action__date")`, то сортировать будет по всем активностям данного объекта, а мне надо учесть только определенный тип.

Если выбрать объекты в массив, а потом в ручную сортировать, идея не самая лучшая, объектов очень много, а к каждого объекта много активностей.

**Обновление 2**:

```
class Lesson(BaseModel):
    __metaclass__ = LessonMetaClass
    ...
    # Еще много полей

class Action(BaseModel):
    lesson = models.ForeignKey('Lesson', null=True, related_name="actions")
    type = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

На выходе я хочю получить отсортированный `QuerySet`.

Answer (score 3):

Что значит "по дате активности определённого типа"? Если у вас какая-то iterable коллекция, то можно отсортировать функцией sorted (для списков есть метод сорт). Рисуете функцию, задающую порядок и вперёд. Например:

```
def mycmp(o1, o2):
    if(o1.activity == o2.activity):
        return cmp(o1.date, o2.date)
    else:
        return cmp(o1.activity, o2.activity)
a=sorted(lessons, mycmp)
```

Это немного не то, что надо по условию задачи, но оно (это условие) непонятно. Желательно бы исходное условие пояснее.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Честно сказать вообще не понятно, что вы хотите сделать *отфильтровать* или *отсортировать*

> надо отсортировать объекты типа
> занятие по дате активности
> определенного типа.

если вам нужны уроки только данного типа отсортированные по дате активности, то по идее надо делать так

```
Leson.objects.filter(action__type="w").order_by("-action__date").distinct()
```

если нужны все уроки, отсортированные по типу и дате активности, то

```
Leson.objects.all().order_by("action__type", "-action__date").distinct()
```

если же надо что-то другое, то поясните что именно.

Насколько я понял из обновления у одного урока несколько активностей, собственно в чем и загвоздка получается, только я не понял в каком они отношении. Думаю код моделей бы все прояснил. Вполне возможно, что вам придется фильтровать и сортировать активности, а потом получать уроки этих активностей (опять же, если я все правильно понял). Т.е. что-то вроде

```
Lesson.objects.filter(activity__in=Activity.objects.filter(type="w").order_by('-date'))
```

**Обновление**

В данный момент мне в голову приходит только такой вариант:

```
lessons = []
for active in Active.objects.filter(type='w').order_by('-date'):
    lessons.append(active.lesson)
```

**Обновление 2**

Тогда вам надо смотреть на [raw sql queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/):

```
lessons = Lesson.objects.raw("""SELECT DISTINCT <you fields>
                                FROM youapp_lesson AS l INNER JOIN
                                youapp_active AS a ON a.lesson_id = l.id
                                WHERE a.type='w'
                                ORDER BY a.date DESC""")
```

**P.S.** Кстати, еще очень хорошо посмотреть что формирует обычный ORM запрос. Очень помогает определить в каком направлении и как надо двигаться.

Comment: Не прокатит. Так как вы написали мы отсортируем активности. Когда мы будем извлекать вопросы, они будут в порядке следования вопросов. Проверено опытным путем, еще до задания вопроса.

Comment: Тем не менее покажите код ваших моделей. Возможно то, что вы хотите можно сделать другим путем

Comment: Опять же, вы предлагаете создавать массив. Не катит. У меня многоступенчатый фильтр. Да и объектов слишком много.

Comment: Скажите, вы нашли подходящее решение?

Comment: К сожалению, пока отложил задачу, так как решения не нашел.

Comment: Так а последний мой вариант с raw sql вам не подошел?

Answer (score 1):

возможно вам поможет мой опыт в чем то подобном:
у меня стояла зада добавить множество фильтров сортировки которые могут быть иногда "пустыми", при помощи регекспов у меня получилось воспроизвести все что мне нужно

дополнительно я использовал django-sorting, django-pagination (их можно найти на гит хабе)
часть кода из views:

```
if request.GET.get('phone'):
    phone = request.GET.get('phone')
else : 
    phone = r'^[0-9]'

if request.GET.get('poz'):
    poz = request.GET.get('poz')
else :
    poz = r'^[0-9]'

acc = accounts.objects.filter(name__regex=poz).filter(account__regex=phone).exclude(status=9)
```

django-sorting легко настраиваемый

ЗЫ
если вы получили QuerySet и потом хотите что то с ним делать , то это тоже не проблема :

```
>>> acc = accounts.objects.all()
>>> acc
[<accounts: 80>, <accounts: 50000000>, <accounts: 093333335>,  '...(remaining elements truncated)...']
>>> acc.exclude(status=9)
[<accounts: 50363230>, <accounts: 09339123115>, <accounts: 80>, <accounts: 8505023138196>,  '...(remaining elements truncated)...']
>>> acc.filter(id=4)
[<accounts: 80>]
```

то есть вы можете отсортировать тех у которых есть активности типа "w", а потом уже отдельно отфильтровать как вам удобно :
как то так

```
type_w = Leson.objects.filter(action__type="w")
type_w.order_by("-action__date")
```